# Search for products in database with AI

Tags: python, mariadb, openai-api

I'm in search of an artificial intelligence capable of conducting advanced searches in a product database. Let's imagine I have a range of stored products, for instance:

"Yellow nail varnish 1560"

I'd like this AI to perform searches using specific terms, for example:

```
"varnish"
"nails 1560"
"yellow nail varnish"
"varnish 1560"
"varnish"
"a series of nails 1500"
```

As you'll notice, as the list progresses, the terms become more diverse compared to the original product name. There are even spelling errors like "varnish". My goal is to manipulate words with the AI's help so that similar or equivalent terms, such as "varnish" and "barnish", yield the same search results.

Additionally, I'd like this AI to recognize terms in different languages. For instance, it should understand that "varnish" in English is equivalent to "barniz" in Spanish and be able to conduct searches in multiple languages.

I'm working in Python and I'm open to using tools like OpenAI or other technologies to enable these advanced searches in my database, retrieving relevant products.

Any ideas or suggestions on how I could go about this project?

Thank you for any assistance you can provide!